# New site created without any structure or channels

Tags: ee3, channel, multi-site-manager, structure

I'm running an EE 3 install using multiple site manager. When clicking create new site, I can create a new site and name it properly, but it is not importing the channels and field groups from the previous site, nor am I getting any sort of option to import/duplicate/copy them.

I've spent time researching the problem and the nearest I can come is that in EE 2, you were given the option to select which items to duplicate when running MSM, but in EE 3 and beyond, it simply duplicates the site that you currently have selected. Is this untrue or is there some step I'm missing to allow me to duplicate the channels and structure of the other site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your copy of EE3 MSM is working properly - when you create a new MSM site initially it is empty of templates, data and channels.

The value of MSM is that you can share information between MSM sites - so you can access all the channel information in the other sites from tag-calls in your templates, and simply copy the templates from other sites to your new MSM site if you need to duplicate designs etc.

EE 3.3.0 introduced a facility called [Channel Sets](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/sets.html) to export / import channel definitions which you can then reimport to other sites - if you export a channel set from an site, when you import it to another site it creates a copy of the channel along with any custom fields, categories or statuses that the channel definition uses: it is possible that this feature will enable you to do what you need to.

HTH

Comment: Channel sets ended up getting me what I needed, thank you.